# setting the attr of printed text?

Tags: hover, raphael, attr

I am working out a slick raphael display, yet i cannot seem to set the attr of a print()'d text element on hover after instantiating:

```
var w = Raphael("weddings", 85, 30);
var fonts = [0, w.getFont("helvetica-neue-thin"), w.getFont("arial")];
w.print(0, 15, "Weddings", fonts[1], 20).attr({fill: "#000000"});
```

the following produces no results:

```
$("#weddings").hover(function () {
w.attr("color", "#000");
},
function () {
w.attr("color", "#FFFFFF");
});
```

I thought that:

```
w.print.attr("color", "#FFFFFF");
```

might work, but it doesn't. i'm missing something here? any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you register the font first? See the [.registerFont() function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.registerFont).

I have a faint suspicion, however, that you don't actually want to render the font in this complex way, but simply want to write some text to the screen and then alter it on hover. If so, there's an infinitely easier way:

```
var w = Raphael(0, 0, 85, 30);
var text = w.text(0, 15, "Weddings").attr({'font-family': "helvetica-neue-thin", 'text-anchor': 'start', 'fill': '#000'});

text.hover(
    function () {
        this.attr("fill", "#F00");
    },
    function () {
        this.attr("fill", "#000");
    }
 );
```

(You'll still need to load the font somewhere since it's not standard, but that's your business.)

Comment: ok, i made it work! the 'text' method as you describe renders text in a way that is pixelated and i require anti-aliased text... i did apply your same logic to the print method and invoke the hover via element id for consistency in the hover area as a rectangle... also, i notice that i referred to 'fill' as 'color' in my original question, so that's another thing for which to watch... works like a charm! thanks!